# How to get a Location and its Temperature in Android?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-location

In here I'm using 'Location Manager' to find the current location and 'Sensor Manager' to get the current temperature. When I'm using the 'Location Manager' app is crashed displaying this error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "network" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

Below is the code for 'Location Manager' and 'Sensor Manager'

```
**MainActivity.java**

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener{

        protected LocationManager locationManager;
        protected LocationListener locationListener;
        protected Context context;

        private SensorManager mSensorManager;
        private Sensor mTemperature;
        private final static String NOT_SUPPORTED_MESSAGE = "Sorry, sensor not available for this device.";

        // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

        // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1; // 1 minute

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, this);
    }


    @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationTextView.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("Latitude","disable");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("Latitude","enable");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d("Latitude","status");
        }


       mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            mTemperature= mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE); // requires API level 14.
        }
        if (mTemperature == null) {
            temperatureTextView.setText(NOT_SUPPORTED_MESSAGE);
        }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mTemperature, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float ambient_temperature = event.values[0];
        temperatureTextView.setText(String.valueOf(ambient_temperature) + getResources().getString(R.string.celsius));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
    }

    }
```

Comment: you forget to add permission in manifest file. just add this problem will be solve.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your android manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

And dont forget to ask for the Location permission.